# InterceptTouchEvent for a ViewGroup with a ViewPager inside

Tags: android, events

I have a `ViewGroup` which contains a `ViewPager` , now I want to add the `Long Press` event and `Click` event to the view group(I also need the position mouse event), I tried that:

```
class MyView extends RelativeLayout{
  MyView(Context context){
      ViewPager vp=....
      addView(vp,0);
      ..... // other views

      setOnLongClickListener(this);
      setOnClickListener(this);

      setLongClickable(true);
      setClickable(true);
    }
}
```

But the `longclick` and `click` even are never fired, I think they maybe consumed by the `ViewPager`.

Then I found the `InterceptTouchEvent` maybe work, I tried that:

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable longPressTrigger = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        onMyLongPressed();
    }
};


@Override

public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean intercepted = false;
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            handler.postDelayed(longPressTrigger, 1000);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            handler.removeCallbacks(longPressTrigger);

            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // trigger the touch event
                onMyTouched(event.getX(), event.getY());
            }
            break;
    }

    if (intercepted)
        return true;
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}
```

But I meet some problems:

1 I want the `ViewPager` can still be scrolled event I register the long press and click event. That's what the variable `intercepted` does, but I have no idea how to set it.

2 As shown, the `onMyLongPressed` does not pass any arguments while I need the mouse event position.

Is this possible and anyway to fix it?

Comment: what means of `intercepted`  if it never become true?

Comment: That's the problem, I am not sure how to set the value of `intercepted` in my code.

Comment: if i understand your question correctly putting `setFocusable(true);` on init of your view.

Comment: Does not work. And event the `onLongClick` or `onClick` can be fired, I can not get the mouse position.